# Matlab removal of skull from MRI images in .png format

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have been given data to create spatial priors for GM WM and CSF for a project involving brain segmentation using the level set method.

I am currently stuck on how to remove the skull from Axial coronal and sagittal vies of the brain? essentially i want to extract the brain and just have the GM, WM and CSF intact.

I have attempted using thresholding and `regionprops` in matlab but they leave a piece of the skull always and then remove some of the GM etc.

ideally i would like to make it a built in part of my final piece of code.

Thanks in advance for any advice or guidance on this.

The image below is similar to the data I have, except in my case the skull is not perfectly connected.

How would i extract the CSF and GM and WM from this? i am confused as to how to threshold the image for each type of tissue to create a sort of statistical map.

[image]

Comment: the skull is the outermost layer.  you can just erode until you hit csf, which is black anyway.  otherwise, try to have the patient's skull removed before entering the magnet :p

Comment: you may upload your image as well

Comment: @thang hi unfortunately due to restrictions on the data i am unable to upload it anywhere. it is a basic png image. i have an example that came with come software i downloaded which is very  similar to what i have. How would the erosion work? would it keep the CSF around the brain?

Comment: these are similar to my images, except each plane is its own image:http://www3.gehealthcare.com/en/Products/Categories/Magnetic_Resonance_Imaging/Neuro_Imaging/Cube_2-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your image, it is hard to tell how and whether the extraction method fits in your case. Yet basically, I guess [`bwconncomp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwconncomp.html)/[`bwlabel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) and [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) are supposed to work.

One example:

```
I=imread('mri.jpg');
I=rgb2gray(I);
subplot(1,2,1)
imshow(I)
BW=im2bw(I,graythresh(I));
[L,n]=bwlabel(BW);

mask=ismember(L,2:n);
I1=I.*uint8(mask);
subplot(1,2,2)
imshow(I1)
```

Result (left is the original image, and right is the one after skull removal):

[image]

Comment: hi thanks for that. sorry i am unable to upload any actual data i have. the link above shows similar data. but each plane in the above image is it's own image in my data. i hope this is clear!

Comment: @Ph9 see my update in answer for example.  I suppose the skull removal can be done only on 1 of the 3 images, since you have the corresponding coordinates for different orientations. You can always apply the affine transform to convert one image to another.

Comment: that is great thanks. if i can work on one of them it is a good start.

Comment: Hi guys i am having real trouble with this. It seems when this is used on a real image there is some of the GM and WM being cut out. i will look to see if a real MRI image can be put up.

Comment: @Ph9, the image you just uploaded has very high contrast between the outlier boundary and the inner strucutres, so BW=im2bw(I,graythresh(I)); already extract you the skull. Try imshow(BW) by yourself